# AWS Lambda Java Integration

Tags: aws-lambda, spring-saml, aws-java-sdk

I want to integrate my Saml SSO application with AWS Lambda, but unfortunately my Saml code takes its input as can be seen below in the code. I need to send `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` as input to my java handler. So it requires `request` and `response` as input but my lambda handler takes only input as JSON or java POJO, and I am confused as how to proceed.

```
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    //validation 
    //output
  return authentication;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS team has created a serverless wrapper that exposes request and response objects. This should allow you to do what you need.In their handler you implement a new interface and their underlying functionality returns the request and response to you as AwsProxyRequest and AwsProxyResponse which should be children of HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse.

**Code**

```
public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private SpringLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamLambdaHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context)
            throws IOException {
        if (handler == null) {
            try {
                handler = SpringLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(PetStoreSpringAppConfig.class);
            } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
                log.error("Cannot initialize Spring container", e);
                outputStream.close();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        AwsProxyRequest request = LambdaContainerHandler.getObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, AwsProxyRequest.class);

        AwsProxyResponse resp = handler.proxy(request, context);

        LambdaContainerHandler.getObjectMapper().writeValue(outputStream, resp);
        // just in case it wasn't closed by the mapper
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Source -> https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container